# Get all IP adresses of host with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns

How can I get with Python all IP addresses that belong to host.

For example graph.facebook.com has '157.240.214.1','157.240.27.18','157.240.196.17'

I want all the addresses that DNS get (or maybe more)

Comment: `graph.facebook.com` only has one IPv4 address and one IPv6 address.

Comment: Are you asking about load balancing to multiple IPs?

Comment: `socket.gethostbyname_ex()` will return a list of all the IP addresses.

Comment: @Barmar I update my post with some IP

Comment: You can not do this, at least in the way you seem to present it (`graph.facebook.com` has only one IP address, not 3). For any given name, depending from where you ask, you might get different results. And they might change over time. So no single DNS query can get you what you want. You need to query from different points and collate the results. But it depends a lot on why you need to do so, and for which names, but you don't give details so it seems an X/Y problem. Are you trying to put in place some filtering or things like that?

Comment: Facebook, like many large web sites, makes use of a CDN. These typically work by giving out different IPs depending on the location of the client (so they'll use the shortest path on the network and get good response time). So client A may get one IP, while client B gets a different IP. In general it's not possible for A to find out what IP B will get, and load balancing services can also change these IPs over time.